# Can't Successfully Run AWS Glue Job That Reads From DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have successfully run crawlers that read my table in Dynamodb and also in AWS Reshift. The tables are now in the catalog.
My problem is when running the Glue job to read the data from Dynamodb to Redshift. It doesnt seem to be able to read from Dynamodb.
The error logs contain this

```
2022-02-01 10:16:55,821 WARN [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(69)): Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.31.74.37 executor 1): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup table <TABLE-NAME> in DynamoDB.
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.describeTable(DynamoDBClient.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.ReadIopsCalculator.getThroughput(ReadIopsCalculator.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.ReadIopsCalculator.calculateTargetIops(ReadIopsCalculator.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.initReadManager(AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.<init>(AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DefaultDynamoDBRecordReader.<init>(DefaultDynamoDBRecordReader.java:24)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat.getRecordReader(DynamoDBInputFormat.java:32)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.connections.DynamoConnection.getReader(DynamoConnection.scala:136)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicRecordRDD.compute(DataSource.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.218.180.106] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.handleException(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.runWithRetry(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.describeTable(DynamoDBClient.java:132)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.218.180.106] failed: connect timed out
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6164)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeDescribeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2228)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient$1.call(DynamoDBClient.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient$1.call(DynamoDBClient.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.runWithRetry(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:80)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.218.180.106] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy20.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1331)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 53 more
```

and the complete logs contain this:

```
22/02/01 10:06:07 INFO GlueContext: Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not provided.
```

The role that Glue has been given has administrator access.

Below is the code for the script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="db",
    table_name="db_s3_table",
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=S3bucket_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("column1.s", "string", "column1", "string"),
        ("column2.n", "string", "column2", "long"),
        ("column3.s", "string", "column3", "string"),
        ("partition_0", "string", "partition0", "string"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node Redshift Cluster
RedshiftCluster_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    database="db",
    table_name="db_redshift_db_schema_table",
    redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"],
    transformation_ctx="RedshiftCluster_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: Could you provide your code please?

Comment: @RobertKossendey I have edited the post to add the code.

Comment: Do you have a VPC DynamoDB Endpoint in place?

Comment: @RobertKossendey set up the endpoint and it seems to be working. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I will add this as an answer. Would be great if you could accept + upvote

Comment: @RobertKossendey I marked as correct but unfortunately don't have the reputation to upvote yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you were missing a VPC Endpoint for DynamoDB, since your Glue Jobs run in a private VPC when you write to Redshift.